# Regular Expression to Match RestructreText Syntax?

Tags: python, regex

I have a Regular Expression that it should match `restrutureText` Content, but it goes weirdly.

```
import re

# match regular expression such as
# ===, ---, ^^^ for heading,
# ... anyword:, :anyword: for directive
Regx = re.compile(r'^(====)?|^(-----)?|..\s+\w+::|(^)|(\.\.\s+\w+)?::$|^(\^\^\^\^)|:\w+:')

Text = """
# blogger

`blogger` is a command line utility originally created for converting articles, text, or HTML into speech. This is especially helpful for bloggers who like to provide audio options for their users.

This is a wrapper around a couple of different text to speech tools and is designed to be a simple interface for any user of the `blogger` CLI.

`blogger` is an open-source project from Buster Technologies, the creators of [Buster ERP](https://bustererp.com). Our company published technical and business content on the [Simpler Software Blog](https://bustererp.com/blog) and needed a simple tool to convert articles to audio files.
"""
TrueOrFalse = re.match(Regx, Text)

if TrueOrFalse:
    print 'It is a restructureText.'
else:
    print 'It is a plain text or markdown.'
```

Tested on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/V5m8qW/1), I don't know why my regx match the beginning of text like this. Thanks.

#### Added:

The above snippet, since the inputted text, which is variable `Text`, is `markdown` syntax, it should not match any, yet in `if-statement`, it return `True` and print "It is a restructureText." as a result which is not correct.

The text the my regex should be match is restructureText syntax like this

```
=======
Abathur
=======

.. image:: https://travis-ci.org/yeyuexia/dummie.svg?branch=master
   :target: https://travis-ci.org/yeyuexia/dummie

Simple Template manager to manage template and create project based on template.

Requirements
------------

* Python 3.6+
* Works on Linux, Windows, Mac OSX, BSD

Install
-------

pip::

  pip install abathur
```

My regex match for this inputted text, but it also match with one in the first snippet as well which it should not.

What is wrong with my regular express? how can I fix that? Thanks

Comment: Works for me, once I used brackets around the strings for the ```print``` statements. You should share what goes wrong for you.

Comment: @pinkspikyhairman, the result should be "It is a plain text or markdown." but the result on console is "It is a restructureText." instead.

Comment: @pinkspikyhairman, I have updated my question accordingly, thanks

Comment: In your regex, you have an alternation `(^)` that matches and capture (why?) the beginning of line, it's **always** true. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Toto, indeed, `(^)` I want to match the literal character `^` one or more times instead.

Comment: Then use: `\^+`, that's matching 1 or more carret

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're feeding in multiline text for a regex. You must use the flag `re.MULTILINE` with the regex.

You'll notice, when testing in `regex101.com`, they have `\gm` flags as default. That stands for `global` and `multiline` respectively.

You're most likely trying to match the end of a line using `$` . But your code matches the **end of a string**, the WHOLE string. Also, worth mentioning. `match` should not be used in cases where `^` should match beginning of line, and not beginning of string.

Worth noting, consider using `search` instead of `match` in this case as you need the `^` to match the start of a line, not the start of a string. Even `re.MULTILINE` won't make that work for `match`. Read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

So change this

```py
TrueOrFalse = re.match(Regx, Text)
```

to this

```py
TrueOrFalse = re.search(Regx, Text, re.MULTILINE)
```

Edit: Also, your regex is just completely wrong. You did not mention what you're trying to match in your question. But your regex has an alternative to match just `(^)`, which WILL ALWAYS be a match. So ofcourse it returns a match no matter what. Check your regex101 alternatives, they'll tell you what patterns your regex will match. One of those patterns is just `(^)`

If you'd like us to construct a regex for you, please provide an example showcasing the "restructureText" that you'd like to match.

Comment: thanks but I changed my regx to `TrueOrFalse = re.search(Regx, Text, re.MULTILINE)` but the result did not change, the expression still return True instead of False. On the other hand, on regex101, there are a lot of pink dots at the beginning of the sentence. Thanks.

Comment: Read the full answer please, I've already explained the reasoning behind the regex matching everything.

Comment: I'm not good at Regex I am sorry that. The bug is at `(^)` where I am trying to match litter `^` occurred one or more, and it should be `(\^)` instead. Anyway, thank you every much for helping me with Regex. :)